# Will an options contract always be worth more than it's intrinsic value ? Also if it's very expensive, will it be hard to sell?

Tags: options, equities, american-options

So I'm wanting to know if my call option will be worth more than its intrinsic value and also if lets say it ends up being worth 20k will people be buying it on the market ?

Comment: Do you calculate the intrinsic value using the spot or the forward?

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, consider a call option struck on a stock with current price \$150, strike price \$100, 1 year to maturity, 0% risk free rate, 5% dividend yield and 40% implied volatility.

The intrinsic value is \$50 but the price of the call is \$47.52.